# limitar rango de columnas para el buscador de datatables

Tags: html, bootstrap, datatables

estoy implementando datatables en mi pagina web, y veo que el buscador busca por absolutamente todas las columnas de la tabla, pero me gustaría limitar esas columnas, quiero que solo busque en las 3 primeras columnas.

gracias de antemano

**asi la estoy implementando:**

```
    $("#reservaciones").DataTable({
      "columnDefs": [
        { "searchable": true, "targets": [ 0, 1, 2 ] }
      ]
  })
  })
```

**error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cual es tu codigo, y que realizas las consultas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No utilizo tanto el `datatable`, pero leyendo la documentacion, se puede hacer con `columns.searchable` de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#tabla').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "searchable": true, "targets": [ 0, 1, 2 ] }
  ]
} );
```

En el ejemplo anterior estoy diciendo que solo busque en las columnas `0-1-2`.

**Referencia**

- [columns.searchable](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchable)

Comment: implemente lo que me dices pero me sale un error, en un alert

Comment: @yaidercc que error sale y como lo estas implementando

Comment: mira, ya edite la pregunta, asi la estoy implementando

Comment: @yaidercc y el error??

Comment: ya añadí el error y corregí la implementación que había puesto